# How to completely dispose EaselJS canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm working on a ReactJS app in which I'm using EaselJS to handle multiple canvases, on same page I have to add and remove different canvases on the base of different conditions to render different views. Even after removing a canvas using following code to dispose a canvas component

```
createjs.Touch.disable(this.stage);
this.stage.removeAllChildren();
this.stage.removeAllEventListeners();
this.stage.enableDOMEvents(false);
```

some events are being triggered. After using application for some time it start to use a lot of processing and memory. After having a look at performance tab in developer tools in chrome, I came to know a timer event is being called for every canvas which ever was added. After inspecting code I come to know that

`this.stage.enableMouseOver();`

is setting an `setInterval` timer which is not being removed even after calling all above code and I can't find any way to remove it.

Can anyone please help me to get rid of it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enableMouseOver` method is documented to both add and remove the functionality from a Stage. By passing `0` as the frequency, the interval should be cleared.

```
stage.enableMouseOver(0);
```

From the [documentation](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#method_enableMouseOver):

> Enables or disables (by passing a frequency of 0)

and

> frequency: Optional param specifying the maximum number of times per second to broadcast mouse over/out events. Set to 0 to disable mouse over events completely.

I did a quick pass on the code, and it definitely removes the interval.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to find a way to remove it but missed it :(
I want to request a feature, a function to dispose all events attached to canvas to properly dispose it, instead of detaching different events individually :)

Comment: Feel free to log a request at https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues. Cheers!